# Avoid raw type warnings with a factory that returns a generic object implementing a strategy pattern

Tags: java, generics, strategy-pattern, raw-types

My goal is to have an abstract `Game` class, whose constructor accepts a `GameEngine` that is suitable for derived `Game` classes. This abstract `Game` class will implement generic methods that are suitable for all `Game` implementations. You can think of the `GameEngine` as fulfilling a strategy pattern, to which `Game` delegates methods.

Therefore, upon creating a `Game` with a `GameFactory`, I don't care *what* implementation of `Game` the factory returns. I just want to make sure that the `Game` implementation gets constructed with the appropriate `GameEngine` implementation. However, if I simply return the raw type `Game` from the factory, I of course get `Raw use of parameterized class 'Game'` warnings.

Furthermore, ideally, the `GameFactory.createGame(settings)` method should not have to pass a type, but simply infer the type based on some property of `settings`.

This is the gist of the code I have:

```java
public abstract class GameEngine<T extends Game<T>> {

  public void doSomethingAllEnginesUnderstand(T game);
}

public class LocalGameEngine
    extends GameEngine<LocalGame> {
}

public class RemoteGameEngine
    extends GameEngine<RemoteGame> {
}

public abstract class Game<T extends Game<T>> {

    private final GameEngine<T> gameEngine;

    protected Game(GameEngine<T> gameEngine) {
        this.gameEngine = gameEngine;
    }

    protected abstract T getSelf();
    
    public final void doSomethingAllEnginesUnderstand() {
      gameEngine.doSomethingAllEnginesUnderstand(getSelf());
    }
}

public class LocalGame 
    extends Game<LocalGame> {

    public LocalGame(LocalGameEngine gameEngine) {
        super(gameEngine);
    }

    @Override
    protected LocalGame getSelf() {
        return this;
    }
}

public class RemoteGame 
    extends Game<RemoteGame> {

    public RemoteGame(RemoteGameEngine gameEngine) {
        super(gameEngine);
    }

    @Override
    protected RemoteGame getSelf() {
        return this;
    }
}

public class GameFactory {

  // returns raw type Game
  public Game createGame(GameSettings settings) {
    if(settings.totalPlayers() > 1) {
      return new RemoteGame(new RemoteGameEngine());
    }
    else {
      return new LocalGame(new LocalGameEngine());
    }
  }
}
```

Am I misusing/misunderstanding generics to reach my stated goal? Is it possible to *not* make `Game` a generics class, while still mandating that an appropriate `GameEngine` implementation is passed to the constructor?

Comment: What happens when you return `Game<?>`?

Comment: I wanted to avoid getting into that, because: "it's complicated". ;-) I've tried it, but the gist of it is that I have complex code with my own `Promise` implementation, which ultimately complains that `Inferred type 'Game<capture<? extends Game<?>>>' for type parameter 'T' is not within its bound; should extend 'Game<Game<capture<? extends Game<?>>>>'`, if I make nested calls. I don't understand it enough to ask a concise question about it, so I wanted to see if I could simplify my code instead by doing away with generics for the base `Game` class.

Comment: Not if you want `getSelf()` to function.

Comment: I'm fine with getting rid of `getSelf()`, if possible, but I don't think that that's what you are suggesting. Correct? Ultimately the `GameEngine` implementation must accept only appropriate `Game` implementations, so I guess `getSelf()` must be kept. Unless I am overlooking things.

Answer (score 1):

I feel you overuse the generics and I find `Game<T extends Game<T>>` an overkill. I'd design it in this way:

- Make `LocalGame` and `RemoteGame` extends `Game` (no generic type). Use polymorphysm when you `@Override` the `getSelf` method:

  ```
  public class LocalGame extends Game {

      public LocalGame(LocalGameEngine gameEngine) {
           super(gameEngine);
      }

      @Override
      protected LocalGame getSelf() {
          return this;
      }
  }
  ```

  ```
  public class RemoteGame extends Game {

       public RemoteGame(RemoteGameEngine gameEngine) {
           super(gameEngine);
       }

       @Override
       protected RemoteGame getSelf() {
           return this;
       }
  }
  ```
- Make `LocalGameEngine`  and `RemoteGameEngine` extends `GameEngine` (no generic type)

  ```
  // actuyally, this abstract class can be an interface instead
  public abstract class GameEngine {
      public void doSomethingAllEnginesUnderstand(Game game) {}
  }
  ```

  ```
  public class LocalGameEngine extends GameEngine { }
  ```

  ```
  public class RemoteGameEngine extends GameEngine { }
  ```
- Make `Game` require any subclass of `GameEngine`, the generic part can be used in the constructor only, you don't need to make the whole `Game` generic (`Game<T>`).

  ```
  public abstract static class Game {

      private final GameEngine gameEngine;

      protected <T extends GameEngine> Game(T gameEngine) {
          this.gameEngine = gameEngine;
      }

      protected abstract Game getSelf();

      public final void doSomethingAllEnginesUnderstand() {
          gameEngine.doSomethingAllEnginesUnderstand(getSelf());
      }
  }
  ```
- The whole `GameFactory` becomes simplified:

  ```
  public Game createGame(GameSettings settings) {
      if (settings.totalPlayers() > 1) {
              return new RemoteGame(new RemoteGameEngine());
      } else {
          return new LocalGame(new LocalGameEngine());
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Yes, yes, yes! I felt I was overusing generics as well, and thought something similar should be possible. I just wasn't sure I could override `getSelf()` like that (with subtypes) and didn't know I could use generic types for constructors, like that. The only thing I'm not entirely sure about is whether this construction guarantees that the right `GameEngine` is always used for the right `Game` type, but perhaps I just have to let that constraint go, for simplicity's sake, because this solution appears to make my code a lot less complex.

Comment: I think I may have spoken a bit too soon; in my enthusiasm I forgot that I want specific `GameEngine` method implementations to only accept `Game` implementations that it supports. But before my comments start making less and less sense, I have to think about it more carefully and see if I can achieve those goals with (a variation of) your answer. I'll need to take some rest and will probably come back when I've got a clearer picture of my actual goal. Your answer is very useful, nonetheless.

Comment: Hmm.. I bookmark the question and come back when I get an idea to satisfy all the requirements.